# Generate python unit test document

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, doxygen

My bosses want a list of all the unit tests with their descriptions. Since this will change frequently I'd like to find a way to generate it instead of trying to manually keep it up to date. I am using python for this project. Is there some way to make doxygen or some other tool do this?

Comment: Do you have a continuous integration system which runs your tests and displays the results? If so you could just give them a link to the latest test report, which gives them a nice UI for looking at the available tests.

Comment: We don't have one yet but there is a plan to set one up. When I run the tests I only see the names and descriptions for those that fail. I'd like to be able to generate a list of all of them for the documentation.

Comment: perhaps you can find some inspiration in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138311/python-unittest-reporting-in-html or in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162682/display-python-unittest-results-in-nice-tabular-form